# Null safe Comparator for BigDecimal

Tags: java, spring-boot

I want to have an null safe Comparator. But I tried many ways ii doesn't work.
**getBenefitLimit **is an **BigDecimal **value there no comparing BigDecimal values in Comparator.
In that case how can figure this...

My code and error Using with out null (**Comparator.nullsFirst**)

```
List<ProductBenefitResponse> list = new ArrayList<>(benefitMap.values());
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(ProductBenefitResponse::getDescription).thenComparing(ProductBenefitResponse::getBenefitLimit));
```

Error must be :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
    at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$thenComparing$36697e65$1(Comparator.java:217)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:239)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750)
```

My code and error Using with null (**Comparator.nullsFirst**)

```
List<ProductBenefitResponse> list = new ArrayList<>(benefitMap.values());
list.sort(Comparator.nullsFirst(
        Comparator.comparing(ProductBenefitResponse::getBenefitLimit)
                .thenComparing(ProductBenefitResponse::getDescription)
));
```

Error must be :-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.java:3065)
    at java.base/java.math.BigDecimal.compareTo(BigDecimal.java:228)
    at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$comparing$77a9974f$1(Comparator.java:469)
    at java.base/java.util.Comparator.lambda$thenComparing$36697e65$1(Comparator.java:216)
    at java.base/java.util.Comparators$NullComparator.compare(Comparators.java:83)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:355)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1515)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1750)
```

What is wrong in this code and please give me and answer...

Comment: It sure looks like either `getBenefitsLimit` is returning null.

Comment: Yas but how can I check BigDecimal value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now the `nullsFirst` is applied to the `ProductBenefitResponse` objects, not the `BigDecimal` values.

Try this:

```
Comparator<BigDecimal> bigDecimalComparator = Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder());
list.sort(
    Comparator
        .comparing(ProductBenefitResponse::getDescription)
        .thenComparing(ProductBenefitResponse::getBenefitLimit, bigDecimalComparator)
);
```

By specifying the null-safe comparator for the mapping, it applies to the result of the mapping.

Answer (score 0):

I Found Easy way to Do that Is this correct ?
It return the value I want anyway.

```
List<ProductBenefitResponse> list = new ArrayList<>
(benefitMap.values());list.sort(Comparator.comparing(ProductBenefitResponse::getDescription,Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
                    .thenComparing(ProductBenefitResponse::getBenefitLimit,Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder())));
```